# Предложите способ хранения переменных с значениями int для их сортировки по значению, по названиям переменных и способ отображения

Tags: java, android

Есть допустим переменные int ABC = 10, int  BAC = 9, CBA = 8.  Хочу отображать их на андроиде в виде списка и иметь возможность сортировать по значениям и сортировать переменные по алфавиту. Какие есть для этого есть возможности?

**UPD**

```
 public static Comparator<ModelData> Comparator_name = new Comparator<ModelData>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ModelData o1, ModelData o2) {
                return 0;
            }
        };
```

Comment: Можно через рефлексию доставать имя поля, взять Map<String, Integer>, написать 2 компаратора. В зависимости от необходимости использовать нужный. Удовлетворите интерес, зачем вам это нужно, если не ради прикола?

Comment: Ну, я полагаю, что с отображением на экране трудностей нет. Сортировка по значению-тривиальная штука.Добавляйте их в массив либо в коллекцию, потом Arrays.sort Collections.sort. Если вы хотите сортировать по именам переменных, имеется в виду ABC,BAC,CBA, то увас один путь - рефлексия. У класса есть метод class.getFields, это вернет список всех полей, если поля приватные, то getDeclaredFields.Получив имена, берете их значение и , опять же старым способом сортируете.Но это плохое решение. Именование переменных касается внутренней логики.Исходить из них для отрисовки UI - явная ошибка архитектуры

Comment: Есть список валют, в них хранятся значения.  Так что сортировать их по алфавиту не менее важно, как и по значению.

Comment: С отображением тоже есть вопрос.  Ведь я хочу чтобы в списке отображались и наименование и значение.  Вариант Виктора вроде подходящий, только не знаю как компоратор писать.  Придется читать.  И еще читал что для андроид есть Arraymap это альтернатива hashmap и в java ее нет, сделан специально под андроид

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для вашей задачи не нужно оперировать с именами переменных, хотя это и возможно с помощью рефлексии.

Рефлексия может поломаться, если вы примените обфускацию кода, коя изменит имена переменных. Вам надо иначе.

У вас есть модель данных со значениями **валюта** и **цена**. Значит вам надо создать класс для хранения этих данных c компараторами и `equals&hashCode` как-то так:

```
public class MyData {

    public String name;
    public BigInteger value;

    public MyData(String name, BigInteger value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static Comparator<MyData> COMPARATOR_NAME = (o1, o2) -> o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);

    public static Comparator<MyData> COMPARATOR_VALUE = (o1, o2) -> o1.value.compareTo(o2.value);

    public int hashCode() { return name.hashCode() + value.hashCode(); }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this === other) return true;
        if (getClass() != other.getClass()) return false;

        MyData otherData = (MyData) other;

        if (name.equals(otherData.name)) return false;
        if (value != otherData.value) return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Теперь вы можете эту модель использовать в адаптерах и сортировать как угодно по любому полю. И никакой рефлексии не надо.

Comment: Максимум что я понял это идею. Решил тупо скопировать и пробовать. но это (o1, o2) -> o1.name.compareTo(o2.name)  подчеркивается красным и пишет что lambda expressions are not supported at this language level .  А для Android SDK уже поддерживает Java 8 ?

Comment: @Turalllb, некоторые фичи 8 явы поддерживаются. Лямбды можно и через плагин `retrolamba` использовать или студию 3, градл 3,targetSdk 26 и SourceCompatibility 1.8 прописать в `build.gradle`

Comment: Сложновато сейчас всё это, да и надо бы чтобы и на сдк ранних версий нормально работало. Да и строчку эту подчеркивающуюся я не осознаю даже))

Comment: Ну... Можно по старому написать как то там new Comparator и автодополением все подставится

Comment: добавил в вопрос то ,что получилось с автодополнением . Это равносильно тому что вы написали? Объясните пожалуйста , что делает вообще это строка, что за стрелка, что за значения о1, о2 . Каким образом эта строчка сравнивает ?

Comment: С телефона неудобно. Возвращать надо то что после стрелки в примере. Это позволит сортировать объекты по числу кое сравнение возвращает через Collections.sort(list, comparator)

Comment: Написать то написал всё, но как использовать пока не пойму. Надо выспаться, позже отпишусь, спасибо

Comment: ЮрийСПб,вроде что то понял: Этот класс - модель данных, я создаю для каждой пары (имя-значение) экземпляр этого класса. Могу создать массив объектов этого класса и статические методы этого класса позволят производить сортировку по имени и по значению? Так? и такой массив можно будет вывести на экран подключив к адаптеру.

Comment: Да, всё верно))

Comment: Вот был у меня массив Валюта - цена. Его я создавал вручную в соответствии с json ответом сайта. Требовалось сортировать по значению и по алфавиту. Но раз я его создал вручную, он уже изначально был по алфавиту! Сортировать по значению не проблема. А как надо алфавит, надо было показывать изначальный вариант))) и это я понял, когда сделал уже сортировку вашим методом))) Но всё же не знаю как бы я вывел на экран и название переменной и ключ в каком нибудь адаптаре. И пока не знаю как массив экземпляров вашего класса в адаптаре вызвать. Посплю чуть и гляну)